# php front-controller include hashtag parameter

Tags: php

I'm starting to load every page with a front-controller like this

```
session_start();
require 'content/mysql.php';

[initialize variable]

[initialize function]

$uri_parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$uri_parts[0];

if (file_exists($path))
  require $path;
else
  header( "Location:404.php" );
```

Hoping that is a good base of a front-controller, now my problem was including the hashtag parameter that for example I need to chang tab with bootstrap class

Then the url

```
mypage.php#tab1
```

doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not sent hashtag (anchor tag) to server, you can't get that part at server-side. But there is work-around via JavaScript that you can use it.